# Python can't find namedtuple on Linode Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: python, ubuntu-9.10, linode

I have a Linode running Ubuntu 9.10 with a Python version of 2.6.4rc2

When I try to import namedtuple I get an ImportError.

What could be going wrong? This is a part of the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

`namedtuple` is in [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html).